# JSF 2 - View Parameter validation and redirection

Tags: validation, jsf-2, redirect

We are using JSF 2 + Primefaces + Glassfish + CDI/WELD for development. 
We have a datalist/dataTable of book listings on our search.xhtml page, each rendered as an outputLink. On clicking any entry the view.xhtml is displayed with all the book details. This is the code in our search.xhtml that is invoked:

```
<h:outputLink value="${request.contextPath}/viewBook.xhtml?id=${book.id}">${book.title} 
</h:outputLink>
```

In the viewBook.xhtml, based on the book Id passed in the URL, the details are populated before rendering the page as follows:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{bookBean.id}"/>     
        </f:viewParam>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bookBean.populate}" />
</f:metadata>
```

Our requirement is to validate the Id before rendering the page and if not present in our DB, we need to redirect it to an error page or show the error msg on the same page i.e. search page

We tried validating the Book Id in two different ways:
1. Using validation in the populate method as follows

```
if (bookFound)
{
    //Display details
}
else
{
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    fc.addMessage("id", new FacesMessage("No such book found in the system. Please try again."));
    fc.renderResponse();
}
```

1. By hooking a custom validator in the view.xhtml and throwing a validator exception (Faces message) on the screen. We use CDI-WELD, so we can use injection.

   > ```
   > <f:metadata>
   >     <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{bookBean.id}"/>
   >    <f:validator validatorId="bookIdValidator"/>
   >     </f:viewParam>
   >     <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bookBean.populate}" />
   > </f:metadata>
   > ```

Both these approaches work but they show the error on the view screen, not the search screen.  It is possible to redirect it to an error page using the code:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/error.xhtml");
```

1. Is there a way to handle the validation such that the error messages are displayed on the search page, where the outputLink is clicked. We understand that we need to handle the validation on the search page but how can one associate a validator with the h:outputLink. Can we use h:link alternatively (We need to use GET requests, not POST..so using a commmandLink or Button is not feasible)
2. Is there a better way to redirect to an error page than the way we are doing it.

   > (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/error.xhtml");)

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1):

gkari,

Can you use JSF for navigation? I'm not familiar with WELD, but a pure-JSF solution might work as follows. This assumes you have a backing bean called bookBean. It should have a property called `id`, with a getter (`getId`) and setter (`setId`).

1. Create a blank method in your backing bean. It must take no parameters and return a String.

   ```
   String viewBook() {
       // We'll fill this in later.
       return "success";
   }
   ```
2. Change your `h:outputLink` to an `h:commandLink`, which calls the new method:

   ```
   <h:commandLink action="#{bookBean.viewBook}" />
   ```
3. Update the link with an action to set bookBean's `id` property when the link is activated:

   ```
   <h:commandLink action="#{bookBean.viewBook}">
       <f:setPropertyActionListener
           target="#{bookBean.id}"
           value="#{book.id}" />
   </h:commandLink>
   ```
4. Update the new method in your backing bean to do the needed validation, and return a string indicating success or failure:

   ```
   String viewBook() {
       String result;

       if (bookIdIsValid (this.getId()) {
           result = "success";
       } else {
           result = "error";
       }

       return result;
   }
   ```
5. Create navigation rules in your faces-config.xml to route to the correct target, depending on the result code:

   ```
   <navigation-rule>
       <from-view-id>/search.xhtml</from-view-id>
       <navigation-case>
           <from-action>#{bookBean.viewBook}</from-action>
           <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
           <to-view-id>/viewBook.xhtml</to-view-id>
       </navigation-case>
       <navigation-case>
           <from-action>#{bookBean.viewBook}</from-action>
           <from-outcome>error</from-outcome>
           <to-view-id>/error.xhtml</to-view-id>
       </navigation-case>
   </navigation-rule>
   ```

This allows the backing bean to indicate the result to JSF, and the JSF library will handle redirecting to the appropriate location.

Comment: Hi GargantuChet,

Thank you for your reply. 

While we understand that we can make this work using commandButtons and commandLinks, we want to use 'GET' requests and not 'POSTS'. Hence, the outputLink. Can we use any alternatives? 

Thanks,
gkari

Comment: May I ask why GET is necessary instead of POST? That is, what benefits do you gain from using GET that you wish to preserve?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem you are having is that you are creating a FacesMessage on one page yet want to have it displayed on another.  You'll need to stash the FacesMessage into the users session (or possibly a shorter lived scope if available) and then pull it out on the page in which you want it displayed.

There are some attempts at automating this:

There is a Flash scope in JSF 2 and a method setKeepMessages.  You can try this, but I haven't had much luck with it.

There is copy-and-paste phase listener solution discussed here: http://ocpsoft.com/java/persist-and-pass-facesmessages-over-page-redirects/

Displaying messages across redirects is also a feature of Seam 3.